# Running script on EC2 launch automatically during cluster creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am creating a ECS cluster (EC2 launch type) using the ecs-cli. I want to run a script to modify vm.max_map_count setting in /etc/sysctl.conf once the EC2 instance is created. At the moment, I am doing it manually by ssh'ing into the instance and running the script as sudo.

Is it possible to run automation script on the EC2 instance created as part of cluster creation? Any reference/documentation will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: The best place is the UserData, I'm guessing you know this already? Doing it at cluster creation is to early, you want it when the EC2's are being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've tagged your question with `amazon-cloudformation` I assume that you are defining your ECS container instances using CFN.

If so, you can use [UserData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-userdata) in your `AWS::EC2::Instance` to execute commands when the instances are launched:

- [Running commands on your Linux instance at launch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

You are probably already using it to specify cluster name for the ECS agents running on your instances. So probably you already have something similar in your `UserData`;

```
echo ECS_CLUSTER=${ClusterName} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
echo ECS_BACKEND_HOST= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

You can extend the `UserData` with extra commands that would modify `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

There are some other possibilities, such as using SSM State Manager to perform actions when your instances launch.

Comment: I am new to AWS. Cloudformation is certainly an option. But assuming we don't go that route, would it be possible to invoke Userdata once the EC2 instance is up automatedly

Comment: @Chubsdad `UserData` executes only at launch time. You can look at [SSM Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) to run commands after the instances launch. Its better then ssh'ing into them. You can also use [Lunch Templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-templates.html) and Lunch Configuration to specify UserData. btw, if you don't use CFN, why use cloudformation tag?

Comment: Would --extra-user-data argument to ecs-cli up be an option? From what I read it appears to be inline what I need. And I added CFN, because that is certainly an option that I can consider if nothing else works

Comment: @Chubsdad Yes, `--extra-user-data ` does exactly what I wrote, but I wrote in terms of cfn. The flag: "Specifies additional user data for your container instance. "  :-)

Comment: I kept a 'userdata' file in the current folder and provided that as the argument to --extra-user-data like '--extra-user-data ./userdata'. This however did not work as expected (elasticsearch docker container failed to start citing low vm.max_map). My userdata file is like so 'sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=524288'. What am I missing?

Comment: @Chubsdad Could you clarify what does it mean it didn't work as expected? Any error messages? You can login to your container instance and check for logs in `/var/log` for error messages.

Comment: After ssh into my ECS instance (created to run the cluster), here's what is shows _For documentation, visit http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/ecs
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-113 ~]$ sudo sysctl vm.max_map_count
vm.max_map_count = 65530
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-113 ~]$
_

Comment: The vm.max_map_count which I expected to be 524288 remains 65530. Because of this  my elasticsearch container does not start and hence I can't check the container logs as suggested

Comment: @Chubsdad The commands in user-data execute on the instance, not in the containers. Thus if they fail, you can check for error messages on the instance only in `/var/log/cloud-*.log` files (or similar files).

Comment: I checked the EC2 system logs and it shows the following: **[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Hostname Service.
[    6.266373] cloud-init[3172]: Jul 13 08:33:47 cloud-init[3172]: __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled unknown content-type (text/plain) userdata: 'sudo sysctl -w vm.max_ma...'**

Comment: @Chubsdad Maybe if would be better to make new question with the new info and error messages? This way more people could have a look and provide some insights.

Comment: I could resolve it. I had to follow the guideline at https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html and change my userdata file accordingly